# ByteArrayOutputStream.toString() is giving a garbage value

Tags: java

I have the following line of code:

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(FILE);
```

Due to some restriction on the file we will write the output to the logger so another service can consume the data, so my code changes to:

```
logger.info(baos.toString());
```

The problem is that it's giving some garbage value also and the output of both the code is not same. How can I ensure that `baos.toString()` will give me the same results as `baos.writeTo(FILE)`?

Here is the snapshot:
presto-querylog.log shows output `boas.toString()` and check.log for `baos.writeTo(FILE);`

#### Code for writing

```
private SpecificDatumWriter<UQLMetrics> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(Metrics.getClassSchema());
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private BinaryEncoder encoder =  EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null);
datumWriter.write(metrics, encoder);
encoder.flush();
```

[image: presto-querylog.log shows output boas.toString()]

Comment: Okay, so I'm assuming that `EncoderFactory` is from Avro? You should really clarify that in your question. You're asking for an encoder which will write *binary* data, but then expecting it to be useful *text* data. Basically, don't do that. Decide whether you want the output to be binary or text, make the code reflect that, and make your assumptions reflect that too.

Comment: (I would also suggest you reflect on your use of the term "garbage value" which suggests you believe that someone else's code is doing something wrong... when actually this is "a value I don't understand" but which is actually fine as far as we can tell, now that you've given more context.)

Answer (score 0):

This likely has to do to the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) encoding used for the file vs. the system default ([`Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset())), which is used by [`baos.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString()) to create the string.

Use the same charset for both and you will get the same output.

[`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) does not know about the charset. It works with binary data.

You can use [`ByteArrayOutputStream#toString(Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)) to specify the charset with which the string from the stream will be created.
The charset should be whichever your data is encoded in.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileOutputStream file = ...;
baos.writeTo(file);
```

```
Charset charset = ...; // Whichever charset the string from which `baos` was produced is encoded in
logger.info(baos.toString(charset));
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `toString()` converts the buffer's contents into a string decoding bytes using the platform's default character set. This is not what you want.

You need to know in which character set the information was written into your output stream and then use the method `public String toString(String charsetName)`, so the String is constructed with the correct charset.

In the past, when diagnosing encoding issues, this utility helped me a lot. It's a converter that can convert any string to a Unicode sequence and vise-versa. It is part of my Open Source MgntUtils library.

Here is a code sample:

```
String result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output would be:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

So, I would suggest that you take the text that you are trying to write as a String and convert it to Unicode sequence. Then check if the sequence is the same as bytes that you are writing. If they are the same, then you are working in UTF-8.

Here is the Javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html). The library can be obtained as Maven artifacts [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils), or on the [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) with source code and Javadoc.